# A special construction in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, determinant, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I have a question from my professor' notes. We defined $\Lambda^k(V)$ as the set of all $k$-Tensor' forms (multilinear transformations), $\omega$, which fulfuill $\omega(v_1,...,v_i,v_j,...,v_k)=-\omega(v_1,...,v_j,v_i,...,v_k)$.

> Let $v_1,...,v_{n-1}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\varphi(\omega)=\operatorname{det}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
> v_1\\ 
> \vdots\\ 
> v_{n-1}\\ 
> \omega
> \end{smallmatrix}\right)$. We observe that $\varphi\in\Lambda^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, thus, there exsists a unique $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that 
>   $$\\ \left \langle z,\omega \right \rangle=\varphi(\omega)=\operatorname{det}\left(\begin{smallmatrix} v_1\\ \vdots \\ v_{n-1}\\ \omega  \end{smallmatrix}\right) \
> $$

My question is why is  there a uniuqe $z$ as above?

I know that $\varphi(\omega)$ is some number in $\mathbb{R}$, so I have a lot of options to choose $z$. For example, if $\varphi(\omega)=3$ and $\omega=(2,5,-24)$ and $z=(z_1,z_2,z_3)$, I can find a lot of options such that $2z_1+5z_2-24z_3=3$, so how is $z$ unique?

Comment: That is $\phi$ defined as function of $w$. So your formula should hold for any $w$. In that sense, $z$ is unique.

Comment: Every element of $\Lambda^1(\Bbb R^n)$ is given by a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$. Every such is dot product with some (unique) vector in $\Bbb R^n$.  (Think about the matrix representation of the linear transformation.)